# How to judge if FOREACH iteration variable is null?

Tags: c#, wpf, foreach, iteration

I have a foreach loop.

```
foreach(var item in dataGrid)
        {


        }
```

I need to judge if "item" is null, because when the item is null, i get a NullReferenceException. NOTE: my purpose is not to judge "dataGrid", because for some reasons, this "dataGrid" in my program is never null (its value is 1 when it is actually null or 1), but "item" can be null when "dataGrid" is acutally null.

**The actual question** - How to judge whether item is null?

Comment: You know what a datagrid is and how to do a `foreach`, but you cannot do a simple, single-condition `if`?

Comment: @nvoigt i need bind sourceItem in datagrid and it is better to user foreach for me

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read a basic programming book or tutorial before attempting anything else. You will not get far if you are missing the basics. It will be a lot easier with a solid foundation instead of trial-and-error.

Comment: @nvoigt I agree with you, I have spent a lot of time on reading programming book before, but now really have no time to refresh it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can eliminate *null* items using `Where`:

```
foreach(var item in dataGrid.Where(x => x != null))
```

Comment: Is there a slight performance risk from filtering with LINQ if there is a large datagrid?

Comment: @MarkWalsh No performance hit. `Where` is Lazy. Almost all linq methods are lazy..

Comment: @user3821183 it's just the name of lambda parameter. it represents the items in your dataGrid collection.

Comment: Where is basically implemented like: `public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> selector) { foreach (var item in source) { if (selector(item)) { yield return item; } }`. So there *might* be an ever so slight performance hit by calling a method. Once. And maybe by moving next along source. But it will be hard at the limit of not being measurable at all. -- So I'd definitely see *not* using `Where` as premature optimization

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(var item in dataGrid)
    {
        if(item == null) continue;

        // do your work here...
    }
```

Comment: This is the most elegant in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check it using an IF statement inside the for each loop.

```
foreach(var item in dataGrid) {
    if (item == null) {
        // Do something, throw exception, continue, whatever...
    } else {
        // Do something useful with item...
    }
}
```